# What would cause ClassNotFound in a Scala 3 macro?

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros

Doing reflection in a macro.  Sometimes, only for a few classes (seems to happen for a select few Java classes in a mixed project) Class.forName() doesn't work when testing.

For example this works:

```scala
RType.of[JavaParam[Boolean]] // macro call - compile-time
```

And this fails--for a few certain classes (a Java class, in this case).  All Scala classes and most other Java classes work this way, no problem.

```scala
RType.of("my.samples.JavaParam") // calls Class.forName
```

(This second call *should* reflect on the generic JavaParam class with no types given for the generic parameters.). The success of the first call should prove JavaParam is visible on the classpath, right?  The only difference is the top one is executing at runtime (macro expansion) and the bottom is 100% runtime.  Just to test a theory, I tried this in my test code (runtime), and it succeeded, so yes--it should be visible on the classpath:

```scala
val foo = new JavaParam()
```

Why do I get ClassNotFoundExceptions for this?  And what I can I do fix it?

Comment: Print `classOf[JavaParam[Boolean]]` and check what is the name used by Java for this class. Perhaps it is not `my.samples.JavaParam`.

Comment: Alternatively, ClassLoader used by `RType.of[JavaParam[Boolean]]` might be a different one than what is called by internals of `RType.of(String)`. Which is quite possible if there would be e.g. nested classloaders and the "outer" one loaded `Class` while "inner" one loaded `RType`. Then `Class.forName` could work with different class path than code that runs the macro.